# Using for loops to make a pattern in an array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, initialization, nested-loops

I am trying to figure out how to use nested for loops (shown below) to initialize a pattern in an array. Right now I have all the values set to 1. The desired pattern is below as well (in comment blocks).

```
/*{{1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
    { 1,2,2,2,2,2,1 },
    { 1,2,3,3,3,2,1 },
    { 1,2,3,4,3,2,1 },
    { 1,2,3,3,3,2,1 },
    { 1,2,2,2,2,2,1 },
    { 1,1,1,1,1,1,1 }};*/
```

Supposedly, I should be able to do this using abs (the absolute value function). In the instructions for making the code, it says "The abs function from the  library returns the absolute value of a variable. So abs(v-MIDDLE) will return how far v is from MIDDLE. It will help you to figure out how far you are from the middle of the array."

Is anyone able to help me use the nested loops and the abs function to initialize the proper values?

```
void boardInit(Board board)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_SIZE; ++i) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < BOARD_SIZE; ++j) 
        {
            board[i][j] = '1';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Subtle hint: What’s the grid coordinate of the middle?

Comment: Here's a simple way to figure out how to do this, and it never fails to work. Just take out a blank sheet of paper. Write down using short, simple sentences in plain English, a step-by-step process of doing this. When done, [call your rubber duck for an appointment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Generally, we don't write code for other people, on Stackoverflow. We always refer such questions to your rubber duck. After your rubber duck approves your proposed plan of action, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++. Mission accomplished!

Comment: Yes, the rubber-duck and use-your-debuger comments are like spam here. There is nearly an automatism. Spot newbie with rep 1, then, without reading, downvote, press close, paste the rubber-duck or debuger comment and go away. Not even an attempt to help here. If you do not want to help, then simply go away. Comments like this help yourself stuff are totally meaningless.

Comment: so another typical comment : what did you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you want to create the below pattern with 2 nested `for` loops.

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 2 2 2 2 2 1
1 2 3 3 3 2 1
1 2 3 4 3 2 1
1 2 3 3 3 2 1
1 2 2 2 2 2 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

There are always many possible solutions to solve such a problem.

Let me explain to you an easy to understand and more intuitive approach first.

If you look in the given matrix, then you will find out that the value of each position in the array, is the shortest distance to any border.

So, if you look at a coordinate, consisting of a row and a column, then you can count, how many steps you would need to go in any direction, to cross a border. Then, you can calculate the minimum distance and write this value into the matrix.

Example. Lets say, we are in row 3 and column 3. (At the moment I ignore the fact that we use 0-based indices in C++). If we now check this position, then you will notice, that we would need 3 steps to the left, to cross the left border. And 5 steps to cross the right border. So, the distance to left is 3 and the distance to right is 5. And the minimum distance horizontally is 3.

The same can be done vertically.

Then, after having calculated the minimum distance vertically and horizontally, then we can calculate the minimum distance overall. And, this value we will write to the respective matrix cell for the current row and column.

Becuase in C++ indices start with 0, we need to add a 1 to the result and also to calculate offsets for the border.

All the above thinking and the theoretical designed solution can be nearly 1 to 1 implemented into code.

A possible solution could then look like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    // Chosse any matrix size here
    constexpr size_t MatrixSize = 7u;

    // A 2-dimensional array of integers
    std::array<std::array<int, MatrixSize>, MatrixSize> matrix{};

    // Iterate over all row and oclumns
    for (size_t row{}; row < MatrixSize; ++row) {
        for (size_t column{}; column < MatrixSize; ++column) {

            // So, now, for the current coordinate consisting of row and column

            // Get the distance to a horizontal border
            const int distanceToLeft = column - 0;
            const int distanceToRight = (MatrixSize-1) - column;

            // What is the shortest way horizontally
            const int minimumDistanceHorizontally = std::min(distanceToLeft, distanceToRight);

            // Get the distance to a vertical border
            const int distanceToTop = row - 0;
            const int distanceToBottom = (MatrixSize-1) - row;

            // What is the shortest vertically
            const int minimumDistanceVertically = std::min(distanceToTop, distanceToBottom);

            // What is the shortest way overall
            const int minimumDistanceToAnyBorder = std::min(minimumDistanceHorizontally, minimumDistanceVertically);

            // Set value
            matrix[row][column] = minimumDistanceToAnyBorder + 1;
        }
    }
    for (const auto& row : matrix) {
        for (const int i : row) std::cout << i << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

After analyzing this code, you can see that all the intermediate calculations are `const` and will never change.

So, you could refactor all the intermediate calculations in a one liner.

```
matrix[row][column] = 1 + std::min(std::min(column, MatrixSize-1-column),std::min(row, MatrixSize - 1 - row));
```

But, then, nobody would understand this complex formula later. So, the verbose form is better in the end. And believe me, a modern optimizing compiler will generate the best code out of this.

That example should show, how such problems can be tackled.

EDIT

The following approach could be used to calculate vales based on the middle of matrix.

Also here we start with row and column indices. Let us look on an 8*8 matrix.

Then the indices, either in horizontal of vertical direction, so for columns and rows, would be:

```
0    1    2    3     4     5     6     7
```

The middle value, in this case unfortunately a float would be 3,5. Then, next, we can simply calculate the distance of the row or column to the middle value. The result would be (middle value - coordinate).

```
3.5  2.5  1.5  0.5  -0.5  -1.5  -2.5  -3.5
```

Because we are not interested in negative values, we take the abs-function and then getting:

```
3.5  2.5  1.5  0.5   0.5   1.5   2.5   3.5
```

But we want to get the inverse distance, so how near are the values ro the middle. So, we subtract those intermediate results from the middle value again, resulting in:

```
0    1    2    3     3     2     1     0
```

Then, as in the first example, we take the minimum for the vertical and horizontal direction and will add 1 to show the desired output.

Please see here

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    // Chosse any matrix size here
    constexpr size_t MatrixSize = 7u;

    // A 2-dimensional array of integers
    std::array<std::array<int, MatrixSize>, MatrixSize> matrix{};

    // Iterate over all row and oclumns
    for (size_t row{}; row < MatrixSize; ++row) {
        for (size_t column{}; column < MatrixSize; ++column) {

            // So, now, for the current coordinate consisting of row and column
            // Get the middle Value
            const double middle = (MatrixSize-1) / 2.0;

            // Get the distance from the middle value horizontally
            const int distanceHorizontally = static_cast<int>(middle - std::abs(middle - column));

            // Get the distance from the middle value horizontally
            const int distanceVertically = static_cast<int>(middle - std::abs(middle - row));

            // Get the shortest distance from middle overall
            const int minimumDistanceMiddleOverall = std::min(distanceHorizontally, distanceVertically);

            // Set value
            matrix[row][column] = minimumDistanceMiddleOverall + 1;
        }
    }
    for (const auto& row : matrix) {
        for (const int i : row) std::cout << i << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

I personally find the first approach more intuitive, but, take whatever you want.

In case of questions, please ask, I am happy to help

Comment: Thank you !! Your comments especially helped me work through the logic of it and I was able to write the function needed for my assignment using that!:)